# Как вернуть только ключ , без значения

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Вам даны текущие цены на акции. Вам необходимо выяснить за какие акции
>   дают большую цену.
>
> Input: Словарь (dict), в котором ключи - это рыночный код, а значение
>   - это цена за акцию(float)

```
def best_stock(data):
    # your code here
    list_d= list(data.items())    
    list_d.sort(key=lambda i: i[1])    
    return  data.keys[-1]

assert best_stock({    
        'CAC': 10.0,
        'ATX': 390.2,
        'WIG': 1.2
    }) == 'ATX', "First
```

Вывод должен быть `'ATX'`, мой вывод  `'ATX': 390.2`.

Comment: Я не понял, а проблема то в чем?

Comment: вот проверка условно 
  print("Example:")
    print(best_stock({
        'CAC': 10.0,
        'ATX': 390.2,
        'WIG': 1.2
    }))
возвращать должно ATX , а возвращает  и ключ и значение

Comment: надо data.keys() или list_d.keys(), если вы ошиблись

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Viktorov уже показал как изменить вашу функцию, чтобы она работала правильно.

Я хочу показать немного более оптимальный способ - чтобы найти максимум не обязательно сортировать весь словарь:

```
In [7]: d = {'CAC': 10.0, 'ATX': 390.2, 'WIG': 1.2}

In [8]: res = max(d, key=d.get)

In [9]: res
Out[9]: 'ATX'
```

Comment: Век живи, век учись. Спасибо за этот ответ )

Comment: @Viktorov, в этом вся "соль" SO ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
def best_stock(data):
    list_d= list(data.items())
    list_d.sort(key=lambda i: i[1])
    return  list_d[-1][0]
```

Вы возвращаете `data.keys[-1]`, не понятно зачем, что и приводит к ошибке, т.к. data.keys - это сама функция, а не ее вызов(потерялись скобочки). После того, как вы отсортировали список(`list_d`), вам оттуда и надо взять последний элемент. Так как каждый элемент списка - это пара (валюта, значение) то надо взять первый(нулевой) элемент этой пары, по этому `list_d[-1][0]`